# Server 2008 won't run executables from CMD prompt without .exe extension

Tags: windows-server-2008

On one of our production server 2008 boxes, I cannot run executables from a CMD prompt without supplying the full filename, including the '.exe' extension.  For example, when running "java" produced the usual "is not recognized as an internal or external command" message, I assumed I had borked the path and/or java_home variables.  However, even navigating to the %java_home%\bin directory and typing "java" produced the same error.  If I type "java.exe" instead, all works perfectly.

The problem does not only affect java.exe.  Even Microsoft executables suffer the same problem -- ping fails, ping.exe works; ipconfig fails, ipconfig.exe works; manually created batch file 'test' only works when invoked explicitly as 'test.bat'.

Any bright ideas?

[edit]
Awesome! The issue was a bad value in pathext -- someone had inadvertantly edited the PATHEXT system variable (prepending %java_home%\bin), when that edit should have been on the PATH variable.

Thanks!

Comment: Check your `PATHEXT` System Variable. By default they are:
`.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC`

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'm going to chuck my hat in the ring and say your `PATHEXT` System Variable is hosed or non-existent on that system. Look closely in your environment variables for a duplicate PATHEXT entry too.

The default value of the PATHEXT System Variable should be:

`.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC`

The bad news is that if the server booted up without this, you'll probably need to reboot to get the setting to take effect since it's a System Variable.

Did you remove a program from that box recently?

As per: http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm

> The %PATHEXT% environment variable
>   contains executable file extensions
>   that do not have to be specified for
>   any file in a directory given in the
>   %PATH% variable. The extension .EXE is
>   the most common. Thus the filename
>   sol.exe need only be entered as sol in
>   a command line. If files have the same
>   name but different extensions, the
>   operating system searches in the
>   following order of precedence: .EXE,
>   .COM, .BAT, and .CMD.

Comment: +1. I think a reboot is not needed as long as you use the proper dialog to set the variable and start a new CMD instance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the PATHEXT system variable.

It should show somthing like:

.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

Comment: Oops...missed the comment above.  So yeah...what he said.